# Bind the data to the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ext.net

I populate my list from database like this.

```
List<BObj_person> list = new List<BObj_person>();

BObj_person person = new BObj_person
                    {
                        PersonName = "aaa",
                        PersonSurname = "bbbb",
                        departman = new BObj_departman { DepartmanName = "ccc" }
                    };

list = list.Add(person);
```

`PersonName` and `PersonSurname` are ok, it is shown inside grid but `departmanName` is a problem?? 
how can I bind this list to datagridview like this;  `gridview.DataSource = list;`

**I am using Ext.Net grid
thank you .

Comment: `list=list.Add(person);` ? the `Add` method is void - just do `list.Add(person)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ServerMapping for a ModelField.

```
<ext:ModelField Name="departmanName" ServerMapping="departman.Name;" />

<ext:Column runat="server" DataIndex="departmanName" />
```

Here is [a full example of using ServerMapping](http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Data_Presentation/Server_Mapping/).

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but I might be misunderstanding your question

```
<%# Eval("departman.DepartmanName") %>
```

If you're trying to simplify binding you could add a read-only property to `BObj_person` named `DepartmanName`

```
public class BObj_person
{
    ...
    public string DepartmanName 
    { 
       get { return departman.Name; }
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set `DataSource` of the gridview with the collection and then

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <itemtemplate>
        <p><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "departman.DepartmanName")%></p>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use gridview.ItemsSource. This should be enough to get it working.